# What is the Largest Dimension of the Set of Matrices with $\text{trace} AB = 0$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, trace

Suppose $W$ is a subspace of $M_n(\mathbb{R})$ with property that $\text{trace}(AB) = 0$ for all $A,B \in W$. I want to find the largest possible dimension of $W$.

It seems like the answer is $n(n - 1)/2$, I can find such set of matrices namely the set of all triangular matrices, either upper or lower bot not both, with zero diagonal. They are of the form 
$$\begin{bmatrix}
0 & * & * & * & \dots & * \\ 
0 & 0 & * & * & \dots & *\\
0 & 0 & 0 & * & \dots & *&\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & *\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &\dots & 0\end{bmatrix}$$ 
(or the lower one).

I have problem showing this is the largest dimension it can get. Clearly one of the basis of this subspace is the set of matrices with entry 1 in one of those $*$ and zero otherwise, there are $n(n - 1)/2$ such matrices.

I can show that when adding one more matrix to this basis the property $\text{trace}(AB)$ can no longer hold. Is this the correct way to prove it? Because I think there's an error with this since I start with the uppertriangular then add one more(not general).

Comment: You don't mean, triangular matrices with zero trace; you mean, triangular matrices with zero diagonal.

Comment: The approach of showing that adding another matrix to this subspace, and showing it violates the $\operatorname{trace}(AB) = 0$ condition shows that the subspace is *maximal* in terms of the partial order of subsets. It might be that the triangular matrices with $0$ diagonal are some kind of dead end, but another cleverer approach will yield such a subspace of larger dimension. So yes, your instinct is correct: this approach isn't sufficient to determine a maximum dimension.

Comment: @TheoBendit That is true for general partial orders, but since $\operatorname{tr}(XY)$ defines a nondegenerate, symmetric bilinear form $B$, the partial order here is of inclusion of totally isotropic subspaces of $B$, and Witt's Theorem implies that all maximal such subspaces have the same dimension. (Of course, this is not obvious, so OP should point out this fact or an equivalent justification when writing their proof.) See my answer for another framing of this.

Answer (score 0):

The statement is correct, but the method---showing that your candidate subspace is not a proper subspace of any larger subspace that satisfies the criterion---perhaps requires some additional justification:

**Hint** Show that $B : (X, Y) \mapsto \operatorname{tr}(X Y)$ is a nondegenerate, symmetric bilinear form in this language, the problem asks for the largest dimension of any totally isotropic subspace $W \leq M(n, \Bbb R)$. Then, apply [Witt's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Witt%27s_theorem).

---

Here's an alternative method for showing the claim that doesn't require constructing an explicit candidate, at the cost of using some (well-known) facts about semisimple Lie algebras.

First, we can recognize that $B : (X, Y) \mapsto \operatorname{tr}(X Y)$ coincides with a multiple of the Killing form on the codimension-$1$ subspace $\mathfrak{sl}(n, \Bbb R) := \ker \operatorname{tr}$. But the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{sl}(n, \Bbb R)$ (defined by taking the usual commutator of matrices) is the split real form of a semisimple Lie algebra, so the signature of its Killing form, is equal to the rank of the algebra, namely, $n - 1$, that is, the restriction of $B$ to $\mathfrak{sl}(n, \Bbb R)$ has signature $\left(\frac{1}{2} n (n + 1) - 1, \frac{1}{2} n (n - 1)\right)$.

On the other hand, $M(n, \Bbb R)$ decomposes as the orthogonal direct sum of the span $\operatorname{span}\{1_n\}$ of the identity matrix and $\mathfrak{sl}(n, \Bbb R)$, and $B$ is positive-definite on $\operatorname{span}\{1_n\}$, so $B$ has signature $\left(\frac{1}{2} n (n + 1), \frac{1}{2} n (n - 1)\right)$. Thus, the largest possible dimension of a maximal totally isotropic subspace $W \leq M(n, \Bbb R)$ is $\frac{1}{2} n (n - 1)$.

---

One more method is to find a pseudo-orthogonal basis for $B$ and use that to compute its signature, though arguably this is no easier than finding a candidate maximal subspace in the first place.

> One such basis is $\{E_{ii}\} \cup \{E_{ij} + E_{ij}\}_{i \neq j} \cup \{E_{ij} - E_{ji}\}_{i \neq j}$.

Comment: What does "pseudo-orthogonal" mean, please?

Comment: In analogy to "orthogonal" and "(pseudo-)orthonormal", by "pseudo-orthogonal" I mean that the basis $(E_a)$ satisfies $B(E_a, E_a) \neq 0$ for all $a$ and $B(E_a, E_b) = 0$ for $a \neq b$. Here, "pseudo-" is just a reminder that the the nondegenerate bilinear form need not be definite.